# EF6 code first - remove primary key from column named "id"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

Using C#, .Net Core, Entity Framework 6.0.

How do I explain to EF that the column `public double Id { get; set; }` of my code first model is not the primary key?

I've found [this documentation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/databasegenerated-dataannotations-attribute.aspx) but it doesn't seem to do the trick, as this code:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public double Id { get; set; }
```

still generates code like this upon `add-migration`:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo....",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Double(nullable: false),
            ...
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    ...;
```

I wouldn't like to turn off this feature from EF6 completely, as I need it just for this instance.

Comment: Change the migration code? Or perhaps better, if you're breaking convention for this one table, call the column something else

Comment: While both suggestions are good, for other reasons I cannot do that. Those are my constraints. What I did in the end is creating a new column called `DatabaseId`, and set that one to be the `[Key]`, so this column was released of that duty automatically. Not the solution I searched for, but it seems to do the job with the constraints that I had.